# HTML5 fast rendering with messages from websocket

Tags: html5-canvas

I have a simple sockets server (socket.io) over which I'm sending a stream of images, the performance is way too low when the pixel data is set in canvas (using putImageData). I tried using the below approaches,

- Shadow canvases to draw off screen and then back onto main canvas

  - Type 1) Using drawImage to render off screen canvas
  - Type 2) Using getImageData from offscreen canvas and putImageData on the main canvas
  - Type 3) Using createImageData from offscreen and setting it via putImageData
- Used requestAnimFrame to update the UI during the animation frame updates

I also verified the message latency between my server and client, both of which are really fast, difference of < 50ms on average (which is OK for my app). I also use a base64 string to send the image down from server, all the method computations are really fast. From what I observed is the canvas takes its own sweet time to update the screen even when the pixels are manipulated and set. One more point is that the images that I receive via the sockets are for different regions of an image and not the same ones.

I think I'm missing some basic setting or if the canvas was not meant for this.

Update:
I have also tried using drawImage into Img element and then to canvas, this increases the speed just very little. Once the stream of images starts flowing, then it is again very slow in the UI to update.

Comment: If you're using decently modern web browsers, you could skip the canvas entirely, and just stick the received image data into an image tag using a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: I really need to use canvas, as I'm streaming a single image in bits and changes to the image. Think like a thin rdp client like thing.

Answer (score 0):

getImageData() and putImageData() uploads/downloads image data from GPU RAM to CPU RAM.

Instead, use offscreen `<canvas>` or `<img>` as `drawImage()` image source and don't do any getImageData(). This way the data doesn't round-trip GPU-CPU-GPU after decoding.

If populating the offscreen canvas is the bottleneck, you can also create lightweight image elements on your server-side by using a specially tuned codec (uncompressed PNG), so that the compression does not latency to the process. Then just stream this PNG data as binary websocket frames (no b64).

Comment: ok, what about CreateImageData -> PutImageData, that would be just CPU to GPU?
Like I mentioned, network is never really a problem, as I can get the stuff immediately available when the server sends it. I updated my question on drawImage.

Comment: Eventually everything goes from CPU to GPU. When you do it with native image elements, browser code should do the optimizations for you. However, I believe it's not possible to help you furher until you do an isolated example, like one on jsfiddle.net, where we can run your code and repeat your measurements.

Comment: Instead of using network based resources, you can simply embed the resources in an isolated test case as data URIs and such.